# Idiomatic way to use npm package that is concerned with data retrieval in non-Redux React application?

Tags: reactjs

I am using a private npm package in my React project. The npm package is concerned with data retrieval and not with UI. I am pointing this out since React is a UI library. My question is about how to use this package together with React in a way that is React idiomatic.

Here are the options that I see:

**Create a custom provider and wrap my app with it?**

`<DataRetreivalProvider><App /></DataRetreivalProvider>`

**Create a wrapper for the `npm` package with JSX representations of the methods the npm package exposes, even though they have nothing to do with UI? I have seen some packages do this, like apolloclient with their `<Query>`. I don't know exactly how I would do this, as I fail to see the point of doing this, but I dunno.**

```
return {
    <Client host="127.0.0.1" port="1905">
        <Application ...>
            <Device ... />
        </Application>
    </Connection>
}
```

**Create the objects (`connection` and `application`) in my App component and then pass the data as props to my other components?**

```
// import dataretreival
// create dataretreival client

<App>
    <Component1 client={client}>
    <Component2 client={client}>
</App>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, even if your package is not concerned with UI, since it has to serve it to the components, at least should be concerned with React's lifecycle.

The [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API seems like the ideal fit, would pretty much be your first option, with Context Consumers wrapping other components, more or less like your third option.

For why wrap it like in your second, there are a lots of reasons (easy configuration, can be changed through `state`), but since it's a private package you may not be concerned with any, depends on what you do there really.